# Cache values not appearing in Redis

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-redis

I've got Redis set up as my cache in django, with the following setting:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'localhost:6379',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'PICKLE_VERSION': 1,
        },
    },
}
```

And I'm experimenting with it (new to Redis, want to understand it better). So, I go into my Django shell, and I do:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('asdf', 2)
cache.get('asdf')  # Returns 2
```

And then I go into `redis-cli`, where I expect to see the value, but none of these show any values:

```
KEYS *
GET *
GET 'asdf'
```

What's up with that?

Comment: Did you make sure to connect to the right dabase using [`SELECT`](http://redis.io/commands/select) in the CLI? `INFO KEYSPACE` should show you the number of keys in all databases.

Comment: Yes! This was it, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Redis has 16 databases by default. As @Bernhard says in his comment, you can see how many keys each has with:

```
INFO KEYSPACE
```

Which in my case returned:

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db1:keys=2,expires=2,avg_ttl=504748260
```

And you can `SELECT` the database you want to inspect with:

```
SELECT 1
```

At which point, sure enough, I can see the keys I expected:

```
KEYS *
1) ":1:asdf"
2) ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cacheg2l0bo9z88z8bn4q2ep0andjgo8zrzzk"
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but no matter which database I selected I still got nothing when using django-redis==5.2.0.

When I explicitly specified the db: 

`"OPTIONS": {"DB": 1}`


things worked as expected / mentioned in this answer.

Also, thank you @mlissner!